# Probability distribution of a sum of uniform random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Given a random variable
 $$X = \sum_i^n x_i,$$
where $x_i \in (a_i,b_i)$ are independent uniform random variables, how does one find the probability distribution of $X$?

Comment: There is an article on this for sum of non-IID uniforms. I haven't read the article through, but seems relevant. ON THE DISTRIBUTION OF THE SUM OF n NON-IDENTICALLY
DISTRIBUTED UNIFORM RANDOM VARIABLES http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0411298v1.pdf Oh, also theorem 2.2 here http://www.heldermann-verlag.de/eqc/eqc01_16/eqc16002.pdf

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The sum of $n$ iid random variables with (continuous) uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ has distribution called the [Irwin-Hall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution) distribution. Some details about the distribution, including the CDF, can be found at the above link. One can then get corresponding information for uniforms on $[a,b]$ by linear transformation.

Comment: What is linear transfer? What if the uniforms are not identically distributed?

Comment: I meant linear transformation: $Y$ is uniform om $[a,b]$ iff $\frac{Y-a}{b-a}$ is uniform on $[0,1]$. If not iid, distribution doesn't have a name that I know, which is no problem. But the cdf, even for modestly small $n$, is extremely messy. I once needed it for $8$, and there were some symmetries, but I had to work very hard. This was before good symbolic manipulators.

Comment: Ok, so the distribution when not iid is nameless as far as we know, but then how do I find it? Should I just try to use the convolution as the other poster suggests?

Comment: The convolution process works in principle, it always does. You will find that evaluating the integral is unpleasant at $n=2$, and a real challenge at $n=3$. The real question is: what do you need to know about the sum? Maybe you can get it out of the moment generating function.

Comment: Good point. I need to split the distribution at the mean and then find the mean of the half of the distribution. For each $x_i$ in the sum there will also be $x_j = -x_i$, so I believe the distribution will be symmetric and have a mean of $0$. But I need the mean of only the density on one side of the mean. Being able to calculate the mean for other arbitrary partitions would be useful also.

Comment: Various moments and other statistics that one needs in practical work can be found without explicit formulas for the distribution. Such formulas, if ugly enough, just get in the way.

Comment: Cool. Of course the problem here is that I have to learn moments. They don't exactly seem trivial either.

Comment: If the "real" problem can be stated fairly simply, probablists can (probably) solve it.

Comment: The Irwin-Hall referral is not strictly appropriate, because the OP specifies:  $x_i \in (a_i,b_i)$ ... i.e. that the domain of support for each $x_i$ varies with i. This is different to the Irwin-Hall set-up which assumes that the domain of support is the same for all $x_i$.

Answer (score 1):

The PDF of $X$ is given by the convolution of the PDFs of the variables $x_i$.